# Typical preimage of the commutator map

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

By Goto's theorem for any compact connected semisimple Lie group $G$ of dimension $n$, any element $x\in G$ is a commutator, namely $x=[y,z]$ for some $y, z\in G$. Another way to say it is that the commutator map $\pi:G\times G\rightarrow G$ is surjective. By Sard's Lemma it follows that typical element $w\in G$ is a regular value of $\pi$ and ${\pi}^{-1}(w)\subset G\times G$ is a smooth compact submanifold of dimension $n$.

Question: what is the homeomorphic type of this manifold for typical $w$?

Of course it is tempting to suspect that ${\pi}^{-1}(w)$ is homeomorphic to $G$ but somehow I have difficulty in checking it even in rather simple case of $G=SO(3)$...

Comment: It is natural to divide this preimage by the $G$-action (via conjugation); then it becomes the "relative character variety" of the once-punctured torus. Topology of such varieties was/is extensively studied, but I do not remember the answer off-hand.

Comment: @MoisheKohan , indeed this is how the question appeared, as I need to understand something about character varieties of one-punctured torus, fixing the holonomy element along the loop around the puncture. Could you provide me some standard references, if there are any , of course..

Comment: Goldman wrote extensively on these; apparently, according to [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.498.2715&rep=rep1&type=pdf), for $G=SU(2)$, the variety is homeomorphic to $S^2$, but no proof is given.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the link. If indeed the factorized variety is homeomorphic to $S^2$ in this case then it would not be very surprizing if the preimage is actually homeomorphic to $S^3=SU(2)$ somehow Hopf-fibered over this $S^2$..

Comment: Do we have a good reason to expect that generic fibers are connected?